# jQuery Func Only Works Once Html5 autofocus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a mobile app with a search bar and these functions:

```
$(".dk").hide(0);
  $("#fus").click(function () {
      $(".dk").fadeOut(100);
      $("#sim").removeAttr("autofocus")
  });
 $("#ys").click(function (e) {
    $("#s,#u,#n,#l,#a,#m,.dk").hide(100);
    $("#re,#r").animate({"margin-left": "0px"}, 200);
    $("#s,#u,#n").animate({ "margin-left": "2px"}, 200);
    $("#sim").delay(300).attr({"autofocus": "autofocus"});
    $(".dk").fadeIn(100);       
    e.stopPropagation();
    });
 })
```

### HTML

`<div style="padding-top:10px;" id="toolbar"> <a href="#" id="open-left"></a> 
    <div class="tbar">
        <img style="height:30px;" src="img/cles.png" />
        <div class="ha">
            <img id='ys' style=" height:27px" src="img/searchico.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class='dk'>
    <form id="hif">
        <input id='sim' type="search">
        <img style="position:absolute;height:26px;margin-left:-270px;margin-top:20px;" src="img/searchicog.png">
       </form>
    </div>`

I am trying to fade in and out the `div .dk` (aka the search box). `#Ys` is the search icon, `#sim` is the input field, and `#fus` is the place to click (or tap) to trigger the fadeOut func.

Unfortunately it only autofocuses once.  It also it messes up the `fadeIn` when it does work. After, I have to refresh the page for it to autofocus again.

This YouTube video shows what I want to accomplish: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5n3m2LRy5Y

Comment: didn't think autofocus was supposed to do that after initial focus. Why don't you just... focus the element you want to gain focus?

Comment: also note, `.delay` will not delay `.attr()` or `.focus()` *(hint)*

Comment: @KevinB So if I just set the attribute and dont mess with it in js it will work?

Comment: no, the attribute will do nothing.

Comment: @KevinB Soo how would i focus the element then? Could you post an answer?

Comment: .focus() would do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the autofocus attribute does not cause the focus to change. Instead, you should use the .focus() method.

```
$(".dk").hide(0);
  $("#fus").click(function () {
      $(".dk").fadeOut(100);
      $("#sim").removeAttr("autofocus")
  });
 $("#ys").click(function (e) {
    $("#s,#u,#n,#l,#a,#m,.dk").hide(100);
    $("#re,#r").animate({"margin-left": "0px"}, 200);
    $("#s,#u,#n").animate({ "margin-left": "2px"}, 200);
    $("#sim").delay(300).focus();
    $(".dk").fadeIn(100);       
    e.stopPropagation();
    });
 })
```

Additionally, .delay does not delay non-animations, so to delay the focus, you'll need to use setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#sim").focus()
},300)
```